# How can I set spark.task.maxFailures on AWS databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, aws-databricks

I would like to set spark.task.maxFailures to value more than 4. Using Databricks 6.4 runtime, how can I set this value?

When I execute spark.conf.get("spark.task.maxFailures"), I get below error

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.task.maxFailures
```

Has anyone set this on databricks before?

I understand I can set it up using

```
spark.conf.set("spark.task.maxFailures", 10)
```

however not sure whether this has to be set up at cluster start time or can be set after that?

Comment: you can set it when you are launching your job using spark-submit like --conf spark.task.maxFailures=20 it will override the default conf. this has to be set up at cluster start time ---> not necessary you can set in while job launch as well.

Comment: @kavetiraviteja In databricks, I am not submitting jobs using spark-submit. Any idea of setting this up at databricks?

Comment: You can specify that property when creating the cluster, or creating the job - look into advanced section - it has a window to enter custom spark properties

Comment: Were you able to fetch the value or set inside the Notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update required spark conf set in clusters advanced section .

[image]

[image]